On dialog pop + page pop after unawaited async method ('!_debugLocked': is not true.) - auto_route
I've migrated my code from flutter navigator to a auto route navigator and I'm facing an issue on dialog pop.
I open a dialog and wait its response to decide if I should pop or not my current page.
The response of my dialog is true then I decide to pop my page.
Then because there is a double chained pop I'm receiving an error (that I wasn't receiving on flutter Navigator)
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4817 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
      #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
      #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
      #2      NavigatorState._pushEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4817:12)
      #3      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4774:5)
      #4      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:1436:65)

final bool? result = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => context.router.maybePop(true),
      child: Text('test'),
    ),
  ),
);

_callAsyncCubitMethod(); // take 5 seconds to finish

if (result == true) {
  context.router.maybePop(true);
}

I tried other way to see if it could solve the problem but it didn't work :
if (result == true) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    context.router.maybePop();
  });
}

or
if (result == true) {
  Future.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 0),
    () {
      context.router.maybePop();
    },
  );
}

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem ?
